# What is shared GPU Memory and How is total GPU memory calculated Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, memory, graphics-card, performance, gpu

[**My task manager GPU screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlDkG.png)

**My PC specs**:
1. GPU - GTX 1060 - 6GB
2. Ram - 16 Gigs
3. CPU - Intel Core i7 8750H

**My task manager says that I have**
1. Dedicated GPU - 6 GB (which is correct)
2. Shared GPU - 7.9 GB (shared between RAM and GPU, but how ?)
3. GPU memory - 13.9 GB (I want to know how can I use this whole thing ? if I can that is.)

**So my questions are..

1. How is shared GPU memory determined ?

2. Does my RAM and CPU affect the shared GPU memory ?

3. How can my total GPU memory be used or when does it get used ?**

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't want to. You have plenty of dedicated GPU memory and having the GPU access the motherboard RAM is much slower than accessing the dedicated memory. This shared memory thing is mostly useful for graphics cards that are slow anyway or are heavily VRAM constrained. It will likely cause frame rates to tank on a system like yours. (This is why integrated GPUs use such heavy texture compression.)

Comment: Do you have the onboard GPU enabled?

Comment: Dedicated GPUs can also have shared memory that can be accessed using DMA, so with reasonable efficiency.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yes, it is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

**Dedicated GPU Memory** is the amount of RAM built into the GPU. This RAM is usually called VRAM and can only be used by the GPU. VRAM is high speed and designed for rendering.

**Shared GPU Memory** is a section of your System RAM that your OS allows your GPU to use if the GPU runs out of VRAM. Shared GPU Memory is also used by CPUs with Integrated Graphics since CPUs don't have VRAM (e.g. Intel Core i7 8750H). By default, Windows allows ***up to*** 50% of System RAM to be used. Since System Memory is much slower than VRAM your GPU won't use Shared GPU Memory unless it runs out of VRAM.

**GPU Memory** is the Dedicated GPU Memory added to Shared GPU Memory (6GB + 7.9GB = 13.9GB). It represents the total amount of memory that your GPU can use for rendering.

If your GPU runs out of VRAM and starts using Shared Memory, you will likely notice a decrease in rendering performance in software, applications, and games.

Source: https://www.cgdirector.com/what-is-shared-gpu-memory/