Games laggy- How to disable shared gpu?
I have a setup with 5600G on a Gigabyte motherboard (b550m ds3h ac, Windows 10) and recently attached a discrete card.
When I play some goes it is laggy sometimes and later when I checked the task manager i have seen that the shared gpu memory still is in use.
For this particular game which in total requires around 2GB of video memory, but 1GB is being utilised from system memory as shared GPU.
I have 16GB of system memory and half of it can be utilised as shared GPU memory based on my motherboard config I believe. Using shared GPU making my system under memory pressure and discrete GPU as almost useless.
How can I disable shared GPU memory?
Despite all the things I tried below the shared GPU is still being used.

Ensured display connected directly to card.
Verified in device  manager under display adaptors, only discrete driver showing.
Changing graphic option for game executable under graphic settings.
Disabled integrated graphics in BIOS.
Changed “Initial display output” to PCIe slot in BIOS.
Manually set  UMA frame size in BIOS




The shared graphics memory options in UEFI apply only to the integrated graphics. While you're in there, ensure that Resizeable BAR is enabled for optimal performance. The integrated graphics memory reservation should be disabled if the integrated graphics are disabled.
The "Shared GPU memory usage" in Windows task manager is unrelated to the firmware settings for the integrated graphics, despite the similar naming. More information on those taskbar memory entries: https://superuser.com/a/1763829/596313 This shared memory pool can't be disabled for graphics applications.
Adjusting the game/application setting to use a "real" Fullscreen mode (i.e. Exclusive Fullscreen), will slightly improve VRAM availability for the game/app, but may be detrimental if you switch between the game/app into another application, run multiple displays, or run other apps in the background. Reducing settings, such as texture detail, resolution (or using DLSS or other resolution scaling technology), or MSAA (uncommon these days, but you don't mention the game), will also reduce VRAM utilization.

i have attached a screenshot of my current situation, mostly i am using gameloop android emulator to pubg mobile. The resizable BAR is already enabled. If you look at the image, around 80-90% of VRAM available in my card but still Windows using shared gpu almost like 50-50. This shared gpu is supposed to use when discrete card go out of memory right? is it because i am using an APU?

You mentioned using a discrete GPU, and your screenshot appears to show one. "APU" is an AMD marketing term for a CPU with integrated graphics. As explained in the link I posted, the "Shared GPU Memory" in the task manager is system RAM reserved for the GPU and only used if there is insufficient VRAM. It's typical for shared memory to show use even when there is sufficient VRAM. As of this writing, there are no tools available capable of showing actual VRAM utilization, everything is an estimation of use or reading the amount allocated.

Its actual VRAM utilization because i can see the system memory utilization go up when it is being utilised as shared gpu. I have seen in most cases even though a 50% of system memory available as shared gpu, few MBs upto 100 or 200 only being utilised from it. But in my case its really high making my card useless.

@goodfella No, you're seeing the allocation and estimation of memory utilization change. No tool is currently available to showcase the actual VRAM utilization. Allocation is measureable, actual utilization currently isn't. IHVs expend significant driver work to guide GPU memory utilization optimally. Windows will create a pool of shared memory. Without it, the app, driver, or system would crash anytime memory was allocated outside of VRAM. So it can't be bypassed, except for NVIDIA users and only for CUDA apps.

ok i have an image update, first image shows when i am doing nothing, then 2nd one an open instance of my emulator in background. If you see my shared gpu utilisation as well as system memory utilisation you can see it's correlated. My system memory is almost going to be under pressure. Or you saying system memory usage metric also an estimate? I don't want this completely disabled but make it under at least 512MB.

Low shared memory utilization isn't an indicator that you're not running from VRAM. I have an RTX 4090, when I launch a game my shared memory goes up significantly, but the game runs from the VRAM, performance is excellent despite shared memory allocation. Unlike VRAM, the OS can accurately report system memory utilization, but I don't think it's telling you the story you think it is. The Android emulator mentioned is outside of my experience, but I expect the issues are either with that app (emulation has performance challenges) or your GPU.
